# QClipboard and selectedText() are not equal in QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtextedit, qclipboard

I am doing something in the QTextEdit. I write a slot for the `QClipboard::changed()` signal. In the slot, how can I tell if the text in the clipboard is from my app (not from other apps outside)?

My solution is to compare the text in the clipboard and the selected text:

```
mimeData->text() == textCursor()->selectedText()
```

However, I found that when I selected multiple lines and copied it. The `selectedText()` handle the `\n` as `0` while the `mimeData` handle it as `\n` (that is `10`). So `mimeData->text() != textCursor()->selectedText()`.

By the way, what does `QClipboard::ownsClipboard()` mean? Is it what I am looking for?

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> **bool QClipboard::ownsClipboard() const**
>
> Returns true if this clipboard object owns the clipboard data;
>   otherwise returns false.

So it is what you are looking for.

```
clipboard = QApplication::clipboard();
    connect(clipboard, SIGNAL(changed(QClipboard::Mode)), this, SLOT(your_slot()));
```

slot:

```
void {your class}::your_slot()
{
    if(clipboard->ownsClipboard())
        qDebug()<< "own";
    else
        qDebug()<< "not his own";
}
```

Transcribing from the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextcursor.html#selectedText) of `selectedText()`

> Returns the current selection's text (which may be empty). This only
>   returns the text, with no rich text formatting information. If you
>   want a document fragment (i.e. formatted rich text) use selection()
>   instead.
>
> Note: **If the selection obtained from an editor spans a line break, the
>   text will contain a Unicode U+2029 paragraph separator character
>   instead of a newline \n character. Use QString::replace() to replace
>   these characters with newlines.**

Comment: Thanks! Do you know the subtle difference between `mimeData()->text()` and `selectedText()`?